# How to deal with a plagiarized answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

The answer at https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/182163/15446 is a copy/paste from https://www.modernintimacy.com/13-tips-for-how-to-heal-from-a-toxic-relationship/ (as noted in the comments by @Nobody).

I was confused on what to do (let's assume that the content of the answer is fine in itself)

- downvote? → I do not think so because the answer is fine (per assumption), it is the behavior of the author that is not
- flag? → not sure for what
- edit to add "*source : https://...*" ? → This sounds best for me, though it does not address the issue
- edit to add "*OP: provide your sources: http//...*" ? → this is an answer, not education about authoring

Comment: I believe flag it as abusive is the answer. Let's wait for the mods to answer this officially.

Comment: [This answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4136/546) is an answer to a meta question similar to this meta question.

Answer (score 5):

When you see this kind of stuff, just flag it as rude/abusive as explained [in this answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4136/20058). This is the fastest way to get rid of it (either the system or a moderator will take care of it).

If you're unsure, you can also flag for moderator attention explaining that it's plagiarized with a link to the source.

In any case, once you flagged, you don't need to take any other action (no need to downvote, edit or whatever). This is true also for other posts: e.g., if you see this in a question and not in an answer, you don't need to vote to close either.

Comment: Thanks. My main concern was about the distinction between the content (which, even if plagiarized, may be a good answer), and the lack of sources on itself - your response is clear; On another topic - what is that you measure? :) (and absolutely have a look when you have the opportunity at my favourite birrificio in Torino: http://www.birrificiosanpaolo.it/)

Comment: @WoJ I measure electrical impedance, quantum Hall effect devices and noise ;-) Ah yes, I've heard of it but I haven't had yet the chance to go. So, if you happen to pass from Torino, contact me and let's go for a beer there!

Comment: Will do. I spent some time in Torino some 20 years ago (including at the Politecnico) and made very good friends there, especially one who decided to go into beer production :) Talk to you in real someday.

Comment: @WoJ Beer production is much better than engineering :) There are now many good microbreweries in town and all around the region.